# Add dynamic filters or pagination in ContextBuilder using API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying to force filters or pagination dynamically using a [`ContextBuilder`](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically).

For example, I want to force pagination for the group `public:read`:

```php
namespace App\Serializer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\SerializerContextBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

final class FooContextBuilder implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, ?array $extractedAttributes = null): array
    {
        $context = $this->decorated->createFromRequest($request, $normalization, $extractedAttributes);

        if (($resourceClass === Foo::class
             $context['operation_type'] ?? null) === 'collection' &&
             true === $normalization
        ) {
            if ((isset($context['groups']) &&
                 in_array('public:read', $context['groups'])
            ) {
                $context['filters']['pagination'] = true;
            }
        }

        return $context;
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```yaml
services:
    ...
    App\Serializer\RouteContextBuilder:
        decorates: 'api_platform.serializer.context_builder'
        arguments: [ '@App\Serializer\RouteContextBuilder.inner' ]
        autoconfigure: false
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `$context['filters']` is built as a later stage as it is not available in the `ContextBuilder` yet. `$context['filters']` is available later e.g. in a `DataProvider`.

I tried to change the decoration priority in `services.yml` without success:

```yaml
services:
    App\Serializer\RouteContextBuilder:
        ...
        decoration_priority: -1
```

How can I add dynamic filters or pagination through the context? Is there another interface that can be decorated which is called a later stage of the normalization process and before the filters are applied?

Answer (score 0):

The serialization process is executed after data retrieval this can't work. Use a data Provider.

Comment: Should I decorate `api_platform.collection_data_provider` and mutate the context in `getCollection()` before calling `$this->decorated->getCollection()`? For some reason I always get empty results if I decorate `CollectionDataProvider`.

Comment: It depends, check the doctrine data provider and handle your pagination changes there?